# Stripe (Apple & Google Pay) Integration with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I've been working to accomplish this Integration for over 6 days, I made already the first steps like Create Stripe account, Register Apple Merchant ID and Google Merchant and connect Stripe Account with both Apple and Google Merchant Certificate.
I'm stuck on server-side code (Firebase Cloud Function) and how to create a Payment Intent locally. So, what I want to do is to create the Payment Intent locally (Because my app idea is Invoicing app, the customer may pay 10% or 30% or even 1 dollar from his invoice total amount) and then trigger cloud function to do the rest, And I want to implement ONLY Apple and Google Pay.

Actually, I cross by every single blog, tutorial, and documentation explaining about this topic they still make the payment intent on server side.

My Backend is Firebase.
Stripe Dependency that I'm currently using is "flutter_stripe 1.1.0"

Comment: Have you checked the official plug-in for google party and Apple Pay  pub.dev/packages/pay

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'how to create a Payment Intent locally'? Do you mean entirely on the client? If so, that isn't possible. The Payment Intents APIs require a server-side component.